# Capture iPhoneOSGameView as an Image

Tags: opengl-es, xamarin.ios, drawing

I am writing a signaturecontroller where the user would write his signature and then I take the signature as an image and save post it back to the server.

I quickly found this excellent sample: 
https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/GLPaint-GameView/PaintingView.cs

But I am having trouble saving the result of the painting as an image. The code below just provides a black picture without the actual drawings so how do I paint the result of the drawing to the image context?

```
PaintingView drawingView;
```

...

```
UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(drawingView.Frame.Size); 
var ctx = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
drawingView.Layer.RenderInContext(ctx);
UIImage img = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();                         
UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using OpenGL capturing a screenshot can be done by following Apple instructions in this [technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1704.html).

Normal (non OpenGL) captures can be done following this [note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1703.html).

Comment: both of the links are 404s : (

Comment: @vmachacek Apple removed them (and the wayback machine does not seems to have them). Anyway this is part of the `Capture` methods now available in recent versions Xamarin.iOS (like Herman answered).

Answer (score 1):

MonoTouch provides screen capture convenience methods to capture the contents of the screen while running with UIKit or OpenGL.

UIKit applications

```cs
    var screenshot = UIScreen.MainScreen.Capture ();
```

GLKit applications

```cs
    var screenshot = iPhoneOSGameView.Capture ();
```